# How to generate a barcode from a field in word template?

Tags: ms-word, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I work with MS Dynamics CRM 365 and I try to make a word template. The word template will display some field value. Each of my record have an ID, this ID is store in a field(this field is called ticketnumber) and I want to change the value of this field to a barcode.

I try to follow a tutorial but it doesn't work because the barcode return "ticketnumber" when I scan it. I only use word tool to do it.

I use this code in plain text format area:

```
{ MERGEBARCODE "ticketnumber" \a \t CODE128 }
{ DISPLAYBARCODE "ticketnumber" CODE128 \t \h }
{ { DISPLAYBARCODE "ticketnumber" \a \t CODE128 } }{MERGEBARCODE "ticketnumber" CODE128 }
```

Here's the result of my code:

[image]

It show a barcode, but when I scan it, the result of the scan is "ticketnumber", but should be "SCFR000129". How can I fix this ?

And I have another request, if it's possible, how can I delete the "ticketnumber Code 128" above the barcode and if it's possible how can I have the ticketnumber write below the barcode ?

Answer (score 0):

try this font [Free 3 of 9 Extended Regular](http://www.fontsaddict.com/font/free-3-of-9-extended-regular.html)
it solved similar problems to me, but keep in mind to maximize your font size

Comment: It's work only with computer that already install the font and I do it for someone who doesn't have this font. So it's not the good way to do it.